# How to reduce padding between the icon and text in xamarin button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created a button in my xamarin application and have added an icon to it but there is too much of padding between the icon and the text as shown in the screenshot below.

How can I reduce this space between the two?

I have learnt about the custom renders for Xamarin.Android but its not working for me.

Following is the code for my custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ZeroPaddingRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    class ZeroPaddingRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.SetPadding(0, Control.PaddingTop, 0, Control.PaddingBottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for button

```
 Button btn_login = new Button
 {
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Text = "Login",
  };
btn_login.Image = "login.png";
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The code you posted shows the button but where is the code that brings in the image and the text?

Comment: @hvaughan3 please see the remaining code in the question

Comment: See the solutions here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20787/button-with-an-image-how-to-centre-the-image-horizontally @Abhi